# How to select an item in excel's dropdown list using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I'm trying to make a desktop application (WinForms) that reads an Excel template file and manipulates with it. So far i have managed to write data to specific column and save changes to the file from the application, but i have a problem.

My Excel template file has a drop-down populated with items from another sheet in one column.

Here is how my template looks like:  [My Excel template file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RGj1.jpg)

Sheet2 that populates the dropdown in Sheet1: [Sheet2 - used to populate dropdown in Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNMlz.jpg)

I would like to be able to read those items in my application and select one of them,and also save changes to the file (with the selected item in the dropdown).

If that's not possible, i would like to know if there's any possibility to select an item in a specific index from the application (for example second or third item in the dropdown list and save changes to the file)

I have searched a lot to resolve this issue, but i haven't got any correct answer yet.

Comment: Would help a lot to explain exactly how you're reading from/writing to the Excel file.  There are many ways to do this, and which method you're using will determine what your options are.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I am using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**. To be more specific: **Excel.Application**, **Excel.Worbook**, **Excel.Worksheet**.